# Can I safely replace .takeUntil(Observable.timer(0)) with .take(1)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I was doing some code cleanup for my ngrx project at work and found some RXJS code that was not following our usual practices.  I was wondering if it was safe to replace it with code that does match our usual practices.

This is the code that does not match our normal practices:

```
stream$.takeUntil(Observable.timer(0)).subscribe();
```

I want to know if the code above is equivalent to the following code:

```
stream$.take(1).subscribe();
```

From the [timer documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html) and the [take documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html) that I've read, these two lines of code appear to be equivalent.  Is that the correct conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if the code above is equivalent to the following code:

No, it is not:

```
const stream$ = Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
```

Will give

```
stream$.takeUntil(Observable.timer(0)) // 1, 2, 3
stream$.take(1)                        // 1
```